# Не работает Keras

Tags: python, keras

При импорте Keras мне появляется pygame window, и программа дальше не выполняется. Подскажите, что делать?[image]

Comment: Вы там ценную инфу об ошибках окошком закрыли

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрать `import keras`, так как надо использовать `tf.keras`. И из-за этого в 4 сроке ошибка еще. `sequential` от `tf`, а `layers` от `keras` уже.